# Loop through all BigQuery jobs with Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm using the Google Python API to work with BigQuery.

I'm trying to use `jobs().list()` and `jobs().list_next()` to paginate through
all the jobs in my project.  I'm using a generator with the following code:

```
request = service.jobs().list(projectId=project_id,
                              allUsers=True,
                              stateFilter="done",
                              )
                              # or maxResults=500) 
                              # or maxResults=1000) 
                              # or maxResults=64000)
while request is not None:
    response = request.execute()
    for x in response["jobs"]:
        yield x
    request = service.jobs().list_next(request, response)
```

The problem is that depending on how I use `maxResults`, I get different job lists.

- Using no `maxResults` argument I see 9986 jobs.
- Using `maxResults=500` I see 8596 jobs.
- Using `maxResults=1000` I see 6743 jobs.
- Using `maxResults=64000` I see 6743 jobs.

I'm expecting the number of jobs to be the same each time, so I'm not sure if 
I'm using the API correctly.

What's the correct way to loop through all the jobs in a project?

---

*(updated Wed Aug 14 15:30:29 CDT 2013)*

Still trying to figure this out.  I ran the code @Michael Manoochehri kindly provided three times, using different `maxResults`. Various information about the number of jobs reported each time and how they relate to each other are below:

```
s1 -> no maxResults
s2 -> maxResults=500
s3 -> maxResults=1000

|s1| -> 10112
|s2| -> 8579
|s3| -> 6556

|s1 intersection s2| -> 8578
|s2 difference s1| -> 1
|s1 difference s2| -> 1534

|s1 intersection s3| -> 6556
|s3 difference s1| -> 0
|s1 difference s3| -> 3556

|s3 intersection s2| -> 6398
|s2 difference s3| -> 2181
|s3 difference s2| -> 158
```

I still can't make sense of why I'm not seeing a consistent total number of jobs regardless of the `maxResults` used.

Answer (score 0):

First, the [bigquery_client.py Python module][1] is a great way to access the API from Python, it builds on top of the raw client lib with additional error handling, paging, etc:

I am not sure that you are using the page token properly? Can you verify that you are checking for a nextPageToken? Here's an example I've used before:

```
import httplib2
import pprint
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError

from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run


# Enter your Google Developer Project number
PROJECT_NUMBER = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'

FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json',
                               scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')



def main():

  storage = Storage('bigquery_credentials.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run(FLOW, storage)

  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)

  bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
  jobs = bigquery_service.jobs()

  page_token=None
  count=0

  while True:
    response = list_jobs_page(jobs, page_token)
    if response['jobs'] is not None:
      for job in response['jobs']:
        count += 1
        print '%d. %s\t%s\t%s' % (count,
                                  job['jobReference']['jobId'],
                                  job['state'],
                                  job['errorResult']['reason'] if job.get('errorResult') else '')
    if response.get('nextPageToken'):
      page_token = response['nextPageToken']
    else:
      break




def list_jobs_page(jobs, page_token=None):
  try:
    jobs_list = jobs.list(projectId=PROJECT_NUMBER,
                          projection='minimal',
                          allUsers=True,
                  # You can set a custom maxResults
                          # here
                          # maxResults=500,
                          pageToken=page_token).execute()

    return jobs_list

  except HttpError as err:
    print 'Error:', pprint.pprint(err.content)



if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()


  [1]: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/browse/bq/bigquery_client.py#1078
```

Comment: I think I assumed that the list_next() method was going to take care of the pageToken for me although I didn't find its documentation.

I'll try it the way you have shown.  Thanks!

Comment: I've tried out your code with different values for maxResults, and I still see a different total number of jobs depending on the maxResults value I send in.   In fact, with no maxResults I now see several hundred more jobs (as expected since its been several days and we've been running queries), but with maxResults=500 and maxResults=1000, I see the same number of jobs as I did on July 25.  Is this a bug?